# Extract tag information from sentence (Regex) based on tag data

Tags: python-3.x, regex, match, extract

I have an input corpus which could be of the following formats:

`Name: ABC Def Date: 8-01-09 Age: 5` (First Name + Last Name) //Expected Output: ABC Def

`Name: Abc Date: 8-01-09 Age: 5` (Only first name present) //Expected Output: Abc

`Name ABC Date 8-01-09 Age 5` (No colon after tags) //Expected Output: ABC

`Date 8-01-09 Name ABC DEF Age 5` (Name tag in a random location) //Expected Output: ABC DEF

Current Solution: I am able to hardcode it to search for name and take until the word until the first space. But I am not sure how to extract in cases of First Name+Last Name (essentially until the next tag)

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Will the name always be in all capital letters?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not specify(will update the question). But nope it will not be in all caps

Answer (score 0):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Kqd4pw/1)):

```py
import re

test_cases = [
    "Name: ABC Def Date: 8-01-09 Age: 5",
    "Name: Abc Date: 8-01-09 Age: 5",
    "Name ABC Date 8-01-09 Age 5",
    "Date 8-01-09 Name ABC DEF Age 5",
]

pat = re.compile(r"Name:?\s*(.*?)\s*(?:(?:Date|Age:?\s*\d)|$)")

for t in test_cases:
    m = pat.search(t)
    print(m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
ABC Def
Abc
ABC
ABC DEF
```